# Subclassing Nested Class in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to subclass a nested class as follows:

```
import Foundation

class Blah {
    class BlahNested {
        func name() -> String {
            return "Blah"
        }
    }

    var blah_ : BlahNested
    init() {
        blah_ = Blah.BlahNested()
    }

    func name() -> String {
        return blah_.name()
    }
}


class SubBlah : Blah {
    class BlahNested : Blah.BlahNested {
        override func name() -> String {
            return "SubBlah"
        }
    }

    init() {
        super.init()
        blah_ = SubBlah.BlahNested()   // THIS LINE IS HAVING ISSUES
    }
}
```

It seems that that nested subclass having the same name as the parent (i.e., "BlahNested" being the same in both the parent and the child) is causing issues. Is it required to have different names in such a case? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve here. What's the use case you are going for?

Comment: @macshome frankly, this is just a personal curiosity. I use this design pattern a lot in C++ and C++ does allow nested class to have the same name as the parent's nested class. I was just wondering whether this is possible. If not, it's not a big deal and I'll just use distinct names for the subclasses.

Comment: I don't know that it's possible in swift. It's not a design pattern I've ever run into in Objective-C either.

Comment: I don't know whether swift allow you use same name of nested subclasses. But I don't believe it's a good practice to do so. The code would be unreadable.

Comment: The problem isn't the same names of subtypes (they are two separate types `Blah.BlahNested` and `SubBlah.BlahNested`), the problem is that you want to assign a `SubBlah.BlahNested` instance to an unrelated property of type `Blah.BlahNested`. To the compiler those types have no relationship and the above code also doesn't compile for me (Method does not override any method from its superclass) because of the `override func name`